# Python yield expression misunderstanding

Tags: python, generator

I was reading [this article](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/) and the following program that I have found there is confusing me:

```
def is_palindrome(num):
    if num // 10 == 0:
        return False
    temp = num
    reversed_num = 0

    while temp != 0:
        reversed_num = (reversed_num * 10) + (temp % 10)
        temp = temp // 10

    if num == reversed_num:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def infinite_palindromes():
    num = 0
    while True:
        if is_palindrome(num):
            print("found a palindrome: "+str(num))
            j = (yield num)
            print("j = "+str(j))
            if j is not None:
                num = j
        print("num = "+str(num))
        num +=1

pal_gen = infinite_palindromes()
for i in pal_gen:
    print("i = "+str(i))
    digits = len(str(i))
    pal_gen.send(10 ** (digits))
```

The output starts with:

- num = 0
- num = 1
- num = 2
- num = 3
- num = 4
- num = 5
- num = 6
- num = 7
- num = 8
- num = 9
- num = 10
- found a palindrome: 11
- i = 11
- j = 100
- num = 100
- found a palindrome: 101
- j = None
- num = 101
- num = 102
- num = 103
- num = 104
- num = 105
- num = 106

I do not understand why after *found a palindrome: 101*, there do not appear *i = 101* and
*j = 1000*?

My thoughts:
The program starts. With **for i in pal_gen:**, the program starts to run the while loop in infinite_palindromes(). When then num=10 and num += 1, the if clause is_palindrome is fullfilled. Then, when the program reads "yield", it continuous with **print("i = "+str(i))**. Then, with **pal_gen.send(10 ** (digits))** it goes back to the generator at the line **j = (yield num)** and assigns to j the value 100. Then it assigns to num also 100 and then increases num to 101. Because this is a palindrome, we are again in the if clause, so the program prints "found a palindrome: 101". The next line that the program reads and executes is now again **j = (yield num)**. And I thought that it is the same situation as before, so I imagined that after reading "yield", the program continuous at **print("i = "+str(i))**...and so on.

Comment: Why do you think those *should* appear?

Comment: `send` does not just send a value into the generator, it also runs the next loop of the generator and returns the value. So every time you send a value in, because you don't handle its return value you also drop the first value of the generator afterwards. Except for the first iteration priming the generator, you should not mix `next` / regular iteration and `send`.

Comment: The article is very poorly written, which is reflected in the code quality. the palindrome code can be written as: `def is_palindrome(x): x_str = str(x); return x_str==x_str[::-1]` (yes, semicolons are a thing in Python and I can't write multiline code in a comment). The generator and loop are similarly poorly written so try learning about generators from a different source.

Comment: Please try to write a title that _uniquely describes your question_. We have hundreds of questions in our knowledgebase about `yield`; how is someone looking in search results supposed to know what makes yours different?

Comment: @Scott Hunter. I have included my thoughts now.

Comment: @Masklinn: This sounds very reasonable, but I do not fully comprehend yet what you are writing. Maybe you can give more details?

Comment: @Charles Duffy: I will try to find a better title, but it seems to me that this question is particularly concentrated on a specific misunderstanding of "yield". And, of course, I do not know much about this misunderstanding (maybe it is popular and has a name which I could mention in the title), otherwise I would not need to ask this question.

Comment: @grogor Calling `generator.next` injects a value into the generator *and runs a complete iteration*, essentially it performs a `next()` internally after having set the value in the generator. And thus after njecting the value it returns what the next `yield` generates. By mixing regular iteration (which calls `next()`) and `send` you're skipping an iteration every time.

Comment: What you need to do is call `i = next(pal_gen)` to prime the generator, then always call `i = pal_gen.send(...)` in a `while True` loop.

Comment: It might be a specific misunderstanding, but how is someone seeing the title supposed to know if your misunderstanding is the same as theirs? That remains true even with the edit. Something more specific, such as "Why does yield do X instead of Y?", would make it a lot easier to quickly grasp what you're asking. If the question is too diffuse to distill down that way... it might be worth thinking about how to make something narrower or more specific, next time you're getting ready to ask another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing regular iteration and `send`, this does not work: `send` does not just inject a value into the generator *it also runs an entire iteration and returns the next value*.

So if you're using `send`, you need to perform the entire iteration by hand, using either only `send` (except for the first iteration which is necessarily a `next`) or `next` and `send`.

Here because you're mixing send and regular iteration, you're skipping over every other iteration: an item gets extracted from the generator, then `send` is called, injects a signal, and the next value of the generator is skipped / dropped.

This script shows the issue, the second snippet is what you are doing here:

```py
def iterable():
    v = 0
    while v < 42:
        n = yield v
        v = (v if n is None else n) + 1
        
print("regular iteration")
for i in iterable():
    print(i, end=" ")
print()

print("mix iteration and send")
it = iterable()
for i in it:
    print(i, end=" ")
    # you might thing this has no effect since it sends
    # in the same value it got out, but it skips every 
    # other value
    try:
        it.send(i)
    except StopIteration:
        break
print()

print("only send")
it = iterable()
i = next(it)
while True:
    print(i, end=" ")
    # this is the correct way to handle it
    try:
        i = it.send(i)
    except StopIteration:
        break
print()

print("conditional send, mix with next")
it = iterable()
i = next(it)
while True:
    print(i, end=" ")
    # if you mix next and send it's fine as long as
    # you're coherent and store every value
    try:
        if i % 2:
            i = next(it)
        else:
            i = it.send(i)
    except StopIteration:
        break
print()
```

Since you're send-ing on every iteration, snippet 3 ("only send") is what you need to do.

Comment: thank you! It seems that your script helped a lot. Is the second snippet equivalent to:
it = iterable()
i=next(it)
print(i)
it.send(i)
i=next(it)
print(i)
it.send(i)
i=next(it)
....
print(i) ?

Comment: Kinda, it would be equivalent if `send` did not perform an implicit `next` but it does.

Comment: I thought that is exactly the reason why " it = iterable() i=next(it) print(i) it.send(i) i=next(it) print(i) it.send(i) i=next(it) .... print(i)" produces the same output as the second snippet?

Comment: Ah yes, I mis-indexed the snippets, sorry. That's correct, the `for` loop essentially just calls `next()` and yields each of them until it hits `StopIteration`.

Answer (score 2):

In the first run of `for i in pal_gen:`, the pal_gen detects the palindrome `11`. After which, the generator is paused at the `yield` statement and the body of the loop is executed.

The second palindrome, which is 111 is detected by the `pal_gen.send(10 ** digits)`, this resumes the generator execution with `j`'s value set to `100`.
The generator is then paused again after finding the palindrome `111`, and the control is passed back to the `for i in pal_gen:` loop.

In the second run of the loop `for i in pal_gen:`, it resumes the execution of the generator but since there's nothing sent to the generator, `j`'s value is `None`.

Comment: Thank you. But I still do not understand it. I do not grasp your last paragraph. I have edited my question and wrote my thoughts. Maybe it is now clearer where exactly my confusion lies.

Comment: @grogor , In the second run of the loop `for i in pal_gen:`, the `pal_gen` continues its execution from the point `j = (yield num)`. Now, unlike the last execution of the `pal_gen`, `j`'s value is `None` because in the last execution of the `pal_gen`, it was sent an explicit value of `100` via `pal_gen.send(10 ** digits)`. But here, in the `for i in pal_gen:`, there's nothing sent so `j`'s value is `None`.